# error creating file android

Tags: android, file, filenotfoundexception

When I run the app on Nexus 5 there are no problem with the file but in another smartphone I have a problem, I think it could be the spaces and I deleted it.

The code is :

```
    File file = new File(directory,new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH:mm:ss",Locale.ROOT).format(new Date()).toString()+"-"+idUser+"-"+idTest+".txt");
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

path file: /storage/sdcard0/Nexio/Tests/23-07-2014-16:33:11-alex-0.txt

The directory exists. And the exception is "FileNotFoundException"

Comment: Where is your directory located? Did you look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7658403/713778

Comment: If you are trying to save file in internal storage (private to your app) - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: I think the problem is associated with the name because if the file name is "test.txt" there are no problem.

Comment: While it may not be the present issue (depending on the underlying file system), putting ":" characters in a file name is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

you are probably setting directory with a static string.. that would be my guess.. use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: The problem is because I'm using the character ":" in the name file. I can't understant why but ok, thx you all!